# Replace &lt;br&gt; with \n in sed or PHP in XML file

Tags: xml, bash, ubuntu, sed, str-replace

My `<br>` tags became `&lt;br&gt;` after exporting an XML file. I want to replace every `&lt;br&gt;` with `\n`

Here's an example of a string, where this occurs:

```
to download the ~ &lt;br&gt;to mark on the ~ &lt;br&gt;to attach/enclose the ~
```

I'd like to have:

```
to download the ~ \nto mark on the ~ \nto attach/enclose the ~
```

I tried following way in PHP after doing some research:

```
$filexml='myfile.xml';

$oldxml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ( str_replace( "&lt;br&gt;", "\n", $oldxml->asXml() ) );
$xml->asXml('updated.xml');
```

No strings get replaced, updated.xml has the same content as myfile.xml.

I tried using sed to replace the string:

```
sed -i "s/&lt;br&gt;/\n/g" myfile.xml
```

Again no strings get replaced, myfile.xml stays like it is.

If anyone has an answer I would be thankful!

Comment: What does your input look like, and what does the desired output look like?

Comment: I can't provide all of the input, because I don't know, if I'm allowed to, but here is an example of one line: `"to post the ~ &lt;br&gt;German version of the ~ &lt;br&gt;English version of the ~", I would like to have "to post the ~ \nGerman version of the ~ \nEnglish version of the ~"`.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to turn it into a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry if there is too much stuff, I'm pretty new with asking questions, I'll just keep the important parts.

Comment: Sure, just a representative sample where you demonstrate how what you've tried didn't work, and what you expected instead. Just a handful of occurrences of the string you're trying to replace is probably enough.

Comment: Alright I need a few minutes I think :)

Comment: Hope this is better, I don't know how I could provide better information, since that's all that happens in this case.

Comment: If I run your sed command, I get literal newlines, the file isn't unchanged; to get your desired output, I replace `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: I just tested it with a new file where nothing but my example is the content and yes it worked with `\\n`, but... it doesn't work for my actual xml file, I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the content of my exported XML file, just created a new one and used the sed command for that file. This worked out somehow, but if someone knows why my original XML was so stubborn I'd still be thankful!

Comment: Have you tried to add a structure to your file-type? Please take a look on the following short video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=94&v=fMY5OT_2ZUE) Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that is SDL Trados Studio and not SDL MultiTerm, I can't find the File Types in the Options menu. But still thanks for the link! But my XML does look right.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try via Stream EDitor the following command:

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- sed = Stream EDitor
- -i = in-place (in order to save back to the original file)
- s = the substitute command
- original = the expression or the word to replace
- new = the text to replace with
- g = global (replace all matches not just the first occurrence
- file.txt = the file name

**Edit 1**

This workaround got me the requested for you result, please test it:

```
$str = "&lt;br&gt;to mark on the ~ &lt;br&gt;to attach/enclose the";
$str1=str_replace( "&lt;br&gt;", "\\n", $str);
str_replace ("<br>", "\\n", $str1);
echo $str1;
```

May i ask which application you are using to extract the XML file?

Comment: The question is about replacing `&lt;br&gt;` with `\n`...?

Comment: Yes, exactly, by using Stream EDitor (sed) or PHP.

Comment: Your answer is about replacing "original" with "new", though.

Comment: Please check the explanation beneath the command. In this scenario the command will be   `sed -i 's/&lt;br&gt;/\n/g' myfile.xml`

Comment: Yes. If I replace `new` with `\n`, I get actual linebreaks in my output. Also, in their question, they show the sed command they tried, how is your suggestion explaining why it didnt' work?

Comment: Yes, you are right it works like that, and the command is the same as in the initial question. I will update with the workaround that worked for me and when tested it returned the requested format. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It works for me now after creating a new XML file via copy&paste. My application to extract the XML is SDL MultiTerm. It says UTF-16 encoding if that helps you.

Comment: Have you tried to add a structure to your file-type? Please take a look on the following short video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=94&v=fMY5OT_2ZUE) Hope this will help you.